# How to initialize MSP430FR5969 Comp_E Module

Tags: c, msp430

I've tried to implement a [resistor based temperature sensor](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa071/slaa071.pdf) on a MSP430 FR5969 . The [User Guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau367f/slau367f.pdf) is fairly straightforward on this point. I configured all registers according the user guide but unfortunately I am not able to get the comparator working. Right after starting the comparator it raises an interrupt even if none sensor is connectd. I guess there is an error in my initialization method.

I hope anyone can help with this problem.

Here is the initialization method

```
    //Komperator beenden
stop_COMP();

CECTL0 &= 0x0000;
CEINT &= 0x0000;

// Pinbelegung konfigurieren
connect_input();

switch_pin_to_high_impedance_input(R_SENS_PORT, R_SENS_PIN, -1);
switch_pin_to_high_impedance_input(R_REF_PORT, R_REF_PIN, -1);




CECTL1 &= ~(CEMRVS); //Set to VREF0
CECTL2 &= CERSEL;


/*
 *  If CEREFLx is changed from a non-zero value to another
 *  non-zero value, the interrupt flags may show unpredictable behavior. It is recommended to set CEREFLx
 *  = 00 prior to changing the CEREFLx settings.
 */

CECTL1 |= CEPWRMD_2; // Ultra-low-Power mode
CECTL1 &= ~CEOUTPOL; // nicht invertierender Ausgang
CECTL1 &= ~CEEX;     // Eingänge des Komperators nicht vertauschen


CECTL1 |= CEF; // Ausgang  filtern
CECTL1 |= CEFDLY_1; // RC Glied mit 900 ns als Zeitkonstante
CECTL1 &= ~CEIES; // Rising Edge triggert Interrupt


CECTL2 |= CEREFACC; // Clocked (low power, low accuracy) mode

/*
*   If CEREFLx is changed from a non-zero value to another
*   non-zero value, the interrupt flags may show unpredictable behavior. It is recommended to set CEREFLx
*   = 00 prior to changing the CEREFLx settings.
*/


CECTL2 |= CERS_1; //Vcc with resistor ladder



CECTL2 &= ~CEREFL_3;
CECTL2 |= CEREFL_0; // Referenzspannung: 2.5V
CECTL2 |= CERSEL; // Referenzspannung an negativen Eingang des Komperators legen


CECTL3 |= CEPD4;

setupTimerForMeasurement();
```

Code for pin initialization

```
    //Komparatoreingang
    P1DIR &= ~COMP_PIN;         //Port1.COMP_PIN  als Eingang definieren
    P1SEL0 |= COMP_PIN;         // Aktivieren der Tertiärenfunktion (Komperatoreingang)
    P1SEL1 |= COMP_PIN;
    P1OUT &= ~COMP_PIN;         // Ausgang auf Low setzen

    // RSensPin
    P3DIR |= R_SENS_PIN;            //Port3.R_SENS_PIN  als Ausgang definieren
    P3SEL0 &= ~R_SENS_PIN;          // Aktivieren der Hauptfunktion (GPIO)
    P3SEL1 &= ~R_SENS_PIN;
    P3OUT &= ~R_SENS_PIN;           // Ausgang auf Low setzen

    // RRefPin
    P3DIR |= R_REF_PIN;         //Port3.R_Ref_PIN  als Ausgang definieren
    P3SEL0 &= ~R_REF_PIN;       // Aktivieren der Hauptfunktion (GPIO)
    P3SEL1 &= ~R_REF_PIN;
    P3OUT &= ~R_REF_PIN;        // Ausgang auf Low setzen

    // Konfigurieren des Komperators
    CECTL0 &= ~CEIMEN;          // - Eingang des Komperators auf interne Ref.-Spannung legen

    CECTL0 = CEIPEN | CEIPSEL_4;            // + Eingang des Komperators nicht auf interene Ref.-Spannung legen
                // Kanal 4 (Pin COMP_PIN) an Eingang legen

    CECTL3 |= 1 << CEIPSEL_4;       // Input Buffer deaktvieren, um Energie zu sparen
    //CECTL2 |= CERSEL; //Set Vref to go to (-) terminal


    CECTL2 = CERS_1 | CERSEL | CEREF04;
```

Comment: What do you expect the voltage at an unconnected input to be?

Comment: I configured the input pin to use a pull-down resistor, so it should be around 0V.

Comment: Show the pin initialization.

Comment: I added the pin initialization to my question. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing it in the code, but I don't see that the COMP_E module is being turned on with the CEON bit of the CECTL1 register. (page 708 of SLAU367F)

Comment: At start msp and all its components are initiliazed. The module is turned on later in the main method.

Answer (score 0):

The comments are worse than useless: some are wrong, so you cannot trust any of them.

There are register field settings that are duplicated or overridden by a later assignment; this makes it hard to determine what the final value of the configuration actually is. So I'm not going to try.

Anyway, the problem is that with no sensor connected, the input is floating and could read any value. (PxREN applies only to pins configured as digital I/Os.)